# Removing items inside an array using for loop in lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm trying to use a for loop to destroy objects inside my array like so:

```
for item in self.objects do
    item:removeSelf()
end
```

The self.objects is my array and it contains images I use for animation. If I touch one of these animated objects, it should be destroyed (disappear). My problem is, I'm getting this error message:

> Attempt to call a table value

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error and how to fix it so can somebody please explain how I can remove objects from my array during touch event and why I'm getting this message? Thanks in advance. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A generic for loop of the form `for x in y do...` expects `y` to be an iterator function.  You're passing it a table, hence the error message.

If you just want to iterate over each entry in the table, use `pairs`:

```
for key, item in pairs(self.objects) do
  item:removeSelf()
end
```

See PiL [4.3.5](http://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.5.html) and all of [Chapter 7](http://www.lua.org/pil/7.html) for more info on generic for and iterators.

Comment: Since this is an array, you should use `ipairs`.